# Native layout system is animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, layout

I recently faced an issue where all layouts animated. I can't find out what causes this. Any idea about how can I detect the issue source would be welcome.

**Controller hierarchy:**

- UITabBarController

  - UINavigationControler

    - UIViewController
    - UIPageViewController

      - UICollectionView
      - GoogleMap

**Visible animated stuff: (without being inside animation block)**

- layout:

  - labels and views moving across the cell to the destination position (self-sizing cell)
  - horizontal collection view items comes from corner to their position
- layer:

  - corner radius from 0 to `height/2` animated.
- view:

  - isHidden not works sometimes. It is inside `UIStackView` and when is hide it, it's just push it out from the stack view (visible because of the bug, strange but it's true)
  - setting title on buttons animated (`setTitle:forState:` method. And not the flashing animation, some kind of morphing animation)

**Where are the layout and styling codes?**
first after `viewDidLoad` and inside datasource `didSet` observer

**What about threads?**
I double checked all UI works dispatched in Main queue and `Main Thread Checker` is on.

### - Show me The code !!!

Unfortunately this is an epic production project and changes that caused this issue is `UNKNOWN`. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in some demo app to post it. Sorry

Comment: Some times it's because you use another window. Sometimes because of the code is on another thread. But since you said you already checked main thread, It's interesting for me to see what causes this strange iOS bug.

Comment: No it's not in another window.

Comment: When do the animations occur? Do they correspond to an event? Are they all occurring simultaneously?

Comment: All together simultaneously. Every time something change in the layout system like stackview subview visibility, or label size to fit, or collection view cell self sizing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after about 3 days of investigating and the answer in just a couple of minutes:

In some point of the code there was a animation block:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

I don't know why but this caused all layout animated for the rest of the controller's life (even after animation is done)

So for get around this I tried this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
})
```

Problem solved **BUT!!!** new issue appeared:
**The original animation is not working at all!**

So for the final workaround I changed the code a bit:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

And fortunately it works! I knew:

> all UI works should be done on main thread

and also animation blocks doesn't capture self, and perform their job on current thread. but strangely done.